# Powershell error Remove-AzureStorageBlob Method not found: 'Void

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-powershell

[image]
[image]

Getting Error while calling **Remove-AzureStorageBlob** Powershell

> ```
> Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ConName -Blob $BlobName -Context $Ctx
> Remove-AzureStorageBlob : Method not found: 'Void
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext.set_StartTime(System.DateTime)'.
> At line:1 char:1
> + Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ConName -Blob $BlobName -Context  ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzureStorageBlob], StorageException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.RemoveStorageAzureBlobComm
>    and
> ```

Comment: or, maybe, reinstall azure powershell. error is pretty weird

Comment: [Please change the first image to the commands themselves.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged/320060#320060)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your commands belong to the `AzureRM` powershell module. According to the error message, you may not install it, I can reproduce your issue on my side.

[image]

To fix the issue, follow this doc to install `AzureRM` powershell module, then it will work fine : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0

**Besides**, the `AzureRM` module has been deprecated basically, I recommand you to use the new `Az` module. For more details, see : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-powershell-cross-platform-az-module-replacing-azurerm/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-1.2.0.

Comment: Finally the following helped
1. Uninstall Azure Powershell MSI
2. Use custom powershell script to uninstall-AllModules of AzureRM
3. Install Az Module

Now the issue is resolved.

@JoyWang - Accepting your answer now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

**Remove-AzureStorageBlob** is part of the **deprecated** module AzureRM. The same method in a now module Az has now the name **Remove-AzStorageBlob**. THis fact is not so well documented and it took me a while to find it out.