# Enumerating Azure storage account using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

PowerShell Version:5.1

I am running this command in PowerShell to get a list of blobs in a container.

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName"storageAccountNmae" -StorageAccountKey "Storagekey"

Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $context

$List = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $context -Container "ContainerName" -Blob *

$List | ForEach-Object {Write-Output $_.Name}
```

And getting following error:

```
Get-AzureStorageContainer : Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext.set_StartTime(System.DateTimeOffset)'.
At line:3 char:1
+ Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $context
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzStorageContainer], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageContainerCommand

Get-AzureStorageBlob : Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext.set_StartTime(System.DateTimeOffset)'.
At line:5 char:9
+ $List = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $context -Container "dbbackup"  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzStorageBlob], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageBlobCommand
```

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the error on my system but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615806/powershell-error-remove-azurestorageblob-method-not-found-void) relates to a similar error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Nick Graham's comment I did make sure AzureRm module is uninstalled. Details [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/uninstall-az-ps?view=azps-2.6.0)

Here is my new version of the command that works perfect.

```
$StorageAccountName = "StorageAccountName"
$ContainerName = "ContainerName"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey 'StorageKey'
Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $context
$List = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $context
$List | ForEach-Object {Write-Output $_.Name}
```

Comment: hi @SqlWorldWide can you answer to this query? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76169651/how-to-daily-restore-back-up-from-azure-storage-to-azure-sql-database