# How to daily restore back up from Azure Storage to Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssms, restore

I have a daily backup uploaded to a storage account container in Azure. I want it to restore daily once the back up is in storage account as a scheduled task.
How can I do this?
back up file is .bacpac and destination is Azure SQL Database (not a managed Instance)
Is there any usable T-SQL scripts here so we can use it in a pipeline ADF/ synapse.

RESTORE Database is not working with Azure SQL.Elastic Pools can be used in this scenario?

Comment: Have you read these answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847189/azure-sql-database-bacpac-local-restore?rq=2

Comment: You have to create a routine with Log Apps or ADF

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani that is the initial idea. but is it with T-sql script or something else?

Comment: Yes, you have a variety of scripts if you want or you can pick up actions that comes out of the box

Comment: Can you please share the restore script?. Hope it is T-SQL